# Authentication Handling using HTTPClient

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpclient

I have a class which connects to a Web API, therefore I am initialising a static HTTPClient at top of the class like this

```
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/

This HTTPClient is used by all public methods within the class to contact the API, each method except login() requires a basic authentication header, this header should be in the format:

Authorization: Basic device_id:X-Secret-Key

Where the device_id is a constant for this instance of the class and the secret key a return from the login() method.

Therefore should every method contain:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo)));
```

Where request is the HTTPRequestMessage being created and authInfo is a string in the format device_id:X-Secret-Key.

Or should a every method call a seperate HTTPClient from the one used by the Login() function, declared like:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (device_id, secret_key);
var client = new HttpClient (handler);
```

Thank you for any responses

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header, add it to the httpClient:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo)));
```

After you add this header ONCE, every future calls to the WEB API service should be authorized.

Comment: What does the Bearer Parameter do?