# How to access XML file on employee sharepoint portal?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, web, sharepoint

**Body**
Hi guys. I'll be rather brief if I can so here goes.
I made this app in C# that goes onto my employee portal and automatically gets my shifts for me every 30 minutes my using a web browser control and then it reads the HTML data from that and generates a calendar for me and also provides automated alerts.

**Issue**
Problem is that this web browser uses IE (yeesh help me) and it doesn't work with all parts of the site. I have done some digging around on the site and I found where the ASP site gets the data from: An XML sheet somewhere on the server. I can access this XML sheet, but only if I'm logged in (please see the attached images for more information).

**Current solution**
So my question is this: How do I actually login to this area?
I could login using the webbrowser and then download the XML using that, but it's too slow and too old, so is there a way I can pass my credentials through?
The URL is like this "https://www.mycoles.com.au/api/rosters/nextweek" -- I don't see any thing like ?name=myname ?pass=mypassword... soo yea. (I'm a bit new).

**Further details:**
Application language: C#.
Current technology: Windows forms applications/ IE web browser control.
Site backend: Microsoft Sharepoint.
Anything I'm missing? Please ask..?

**Attached content**
[Mycoles XML Logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2jeP.png)
[Mycoles XML Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2qr1.png)
Update:
So after a while of searching and examining the site, I tried to access the data with a c# webbrowser and it didn't work. It said that it can't download the data, however chrome is able to. Odd. I'm not sure it is an XML file anymore, rather a request and I don't have enough knowledge to work with this, so pointers anyone? Check this site out https://www.mycoles.com.au/api/rosters/nextweek and tell me what you think it is please. Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: I usually debug using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  I first use a standard browser to go to website and capture the sniffer results.  Then compare with c# app that fails.  Usually the fix is to add header to c# app that matches the good web results. The httpclient in Net is very inteligent and doesn't add the headers like a web app.To avoid logins usually a certificate is required or a cookie need to be used.  When a client connects to a web server there is a negotiation that occurs using the headers of the webpage and the headers of the request.The results is in the response headers.

Comment: I looked at the links and it doesn't provide and useful info.  You need to download a sniffer (free) from the web and capture the http packets to determine root cause.  The request/response have a header and a body and the header is missing information.  The cookie is included in the header.   The cookie comes from the first request from server and has an expiration date.  So first time if you login into the server you get a valid cookie, and then you do not have to login again until cookie expires.  Certificate is different that you have to install and usually has a 1 year life.

Comment: @jdweng I found out that there are a few cookies used that are shared between the employee portal and the area storing the XML. I just need a way to login to the server and should be good. I've tried the SharePoint client and also tried HTTPClient but neither work. I'll keep you posted. Do you know how I can actually perform the login? I am really new to this and have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Rather than login it may be better to to go to the URL of the file.  Can you get to the file using a URL using a Windows Explorer (Not webbrowser)? If so you can just get the file directly.  If you are on a corporate network it probably is using Group Policies.  And if you cannot get to the file then your MIS should be able to give you access.  Your user account would need to be added to a Windows Group that has Access to Group on your Local PC and the Disk Server where the files are located.

Comment: Another option is to use FTP with a network credential which will allow you to download the file.  The network credential can either use you login credentials (default) or include a username and password if different than the login you are using on your local PC.  You can also add networkcredential to your httpclient : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609530/authentication-handling-using-httpclient

Comment: Okay... so aparently it is an XML file. I checked by going in my browser and right click > save as and it said XML. I'm thinking about finding out how to use HTMLClient from one of your first suggestions and forging my own cookies to gain access. As far as I know, this area uses 3 authentication cookies. If any one of them is removed or not present, it denies access. So it's just a game of putting the right data in the right location. I have no idea how to even use a HTMLClient, so I will go to MSDN and find out. Waaaaay too much code to sift through there... :)

Comment: Oh and I got wireshark now, so I'm going to use that and see what is what. What do you recommend me doing...? I've used it before, so would I just profile chrome and navigate to the site(s)?

Comment: Filter for only http messages and look at the headers.  The status from a good request is 200 Done.  Any other status is an error.  I usually compare good results from a browser with bad results from httpclient.  Usually you just have to add missing headers to the httprequest.

Comment: Ah... Interesting... Well okay. Thanks for your help.. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports different forms of authentication. Out of the box, Active Directory-based single sign-on is provided, and forms-based (username, password) authentication can be configured.

Typically, organizations use AD SSO for its simplicity. If, once you open your desktop browser and navigate to a SharePoint site, you don't have to enter any credentials and are just logged in, then it's most likely this case. This can be either Kerberos or NTLM. The [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class supports both these methods.